# display an array from another method in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Lab6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int List1[] = new int[10];
        List1[0] = 1;
        List1[1] = 3;
        List1[2] = 4;
        List1[3] = 5;
        List1[4] = 2;
        List1[5] = 6;
        List1[6] = 8;
        List1[7] = 9;
        List1[8] = 2;
        List1[9] = 7;
        toDisplay(List1);

    }
    public static void toDisplay (List1){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i>10; i++){
            System.out.print(List[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

It will not carry over and recognize my List1 array.
How do I display the List1 array in another method without making it a global?

Comment: This code doesn't compile

Comment: He has a back-slash after `main(String[] args) {`.

Comment: and the method declaration for toDisplay is invalid

Comment: You can write `int[] list = {1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 8, 9, 2, 7 };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass an `int[]` to `toDisplay` (and the loop condition should be `<` not `>`). Something like

```
public static void toDisplay (int[] List1){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < List1.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(List1[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `List1` to `int[] List1` in the formal parameters of the `toDisplay` method. By [JCC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), also you should rename the next names:

```
List1 -> list1
toDisplay -> display
```

What about this?

```
public static void display(int[] list){
    Arrays.stream(list).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```